# How to get Noun,Verb,Adjective synset separately?

Tags: java, parsing, stanford-nlp, wordnet

I am using stanford parser for POS tagging and I wand to get separate synset for noun, adjective verb, adverb from the tagging that tagger has done.
e.g.

if my input query is

"**Ganga is India's biggest river and people used to consider it as a God**"

Output of tagger is:

"**Ganga/NNP is/VBZ India/NNP 's/POS biggest/JJS river/NN and/CC people/NNS used/VBN to/TO consider/VB it/PRP as/IN a/DT God/NNP**"

From this I want to separate nouns,verbs, adverbs and adjectives and want to get corrosponding synsets separately.

How can I do this using JAVA programming?

Comment: If the two letters followed by `/` indicate verbs or nouns, you can try `indexOf("/VB")`, `indexOf("/NN")`, etc.

Comment: What is mean by indexOf("/VB")?? What will be it's output?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnShowTagActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
Pattern NounPat=Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]+/NN");
Pattern AdvPat=Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]+/RB");
Pattern AdjPat=Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]+/JJ");
Pattern VerbPat=Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]+/VB.");
String StrToken;
Matcher mat;
StringTokenizer PosToken;
String TempStr;  
int j;
for(int line=0;line<SAPosTagging.tagedReview.length;line++)
{
   try{

   PosToken=new StringTokenizer(SAPosTagging.tagedReview[line]);
   while(PosToken.hasMoreTokens())
   {
       StrToken=PosToken.nextToken();
       mat=NounPat.matcher(StrToken);
       if(mat.matches())
       {
           TempStr=StrToken;
           txtareaExTagText.append("Noun=>"+StrToken);   //textarea to be appended
           j=TempStr.indexOf("/");
           TempStr=TempStr.substring(0,j);
           System.out.print("\tNoun=>"+TempStr);
       }
       mat=VerbPat.matcher(StrToken);
       if(mat.matches())
       {

           txtareaExTagText.append("\tVerb=>"+StrToken);
           TempStr=StrToken;
           j=TempStr.indexOf("/");
           TempStr=TempStr.substring(0,j);
           System.out.print("\tVerb=>"+TempStr);

       }
       mat=AdvPat.matcher(StrToken);
       if(mat.matches())
       {

           txtareaExTagText.append("\tAdverb=>"+StrToken);
           TempStr=StrToken;
           j=TempStr.indexOf("/");
           TempStr=TempStr.substring(0,j);
           System.out.print("\tAdVerb=>"+TempStr);

       }
       mat=AdjPat.matcher(StrToken);
       if(mat.matches())
       {

          txtareaExTagText.append("\tAdjective=>"+StrToken);
           TempStr=StrToken;
           j=TempStr.indexOf("/");
           TempStr=TempStr.substring(0,j);
           System.out.print("\tAdjective=>"+TempStr);

       }  
   }
   System.out.println();
   txtareaExTagText.append("\n\n");
  }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

}

Comment: I think you are not using wordnet for getting synset. I want to get verb, adverb, noun and adjective synset individually from POS tagging